# "const variables" set by a constructor for expressing the bounds of a C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constants

The following code compiles and it seems to run fine:

```
class Test {
  private:
     const unsigned MAX;

  public:

     Test (const unsigned int n) : MAX(n) { }

     void foo () {
         int array[MAX];
         ...
     }

};
```

but is it really OK? I mean:

```
Test a (3);
Test b (8);
```

does `array` actually have 3 and 8 cells respectively?

If so, is it because `array` is an automatic var and gets instantiated with the appropriate dimension?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have written is valid in [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) but **not** valid [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

I am *of course* talking about your use of [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)'s, not the full snippet.

---

When compiling using `g++ -pedantic -ansi -Wall` we get the below warning;

```
foo.cpp: In member function 'void Test::foo()':
foo.cpp:18:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'array' [-Wvla]
```

---

As mentioned in the above warning the pattern you are using is often referred to as using a *variable length array*, which is **standard** in C99 and "allowed" in C++ through a g++ extension.

I'd recommend you to use a STL container instead of hacks as these, for one single reason; what you are doing is not legal, and therefor isn't guaranteed to be portable cross compilers.

Answer (score 4):

Variable length arrays are not standard C++. You could make `Test` a template instead:

```
template <int MAX>
class Test {
public:
    Test () {}

    void foo () {
        int array[MAX];
    }
};

Test<4> t4;
Test<8> t8;
```

Comment: We can't be sure if OP wants to be able to initialize different size classes during runtime (ie. that the size is runtime dependent). He's better off using a container from the STL.

Comment: @refp, in the posted code the values provided are compile time constants. If this is not the case, then I agree, `std:vector<int>` would be preferable.

Comment: I just thought that it should be mentioned, a lot of newcomers become confuse with templates withut a further explanation regarding the fact that it's compile-time.

Comment: templates are good but ... you can't instantiate it if you don't the dimension at compile time! You can't read `n` and then `Test<n> t;`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is not legal C++. If it works on your compiler, it is probably because you are using a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).